# Reference other deployment slot from app service in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I am trying to retrieve the principalId from the staging slot in Bicep. my code is the following.

```
resource App 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2016-08-01' existing = { 
    name: WebAppName
    scope: resourceGroup(ResourceGroupName)
}
...
...
id: App.identity.principalId
stagingId: ?????
```

How can I access the other slot? intellisense does not seem to help me.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want.

```
resource AppStagingSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2016-08-01' existing = { 
   parent: App
   name: 'staging'
   scope: resourceGroup(ResourceGroupName)
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked thank  you. but I did not need the scope.